# C# Microsoft SQL Server 2012 GRANT syntax

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a question about the grant syntax for me specific scenario.

I have created a database whose instance name is : MYINSTANCE
My DB is called: MyDB

I have run an SQL command which makes a new table, and now I want to grant Select and Update privileges to my user.

I am using a connection string as follows with Integrated Security turned on :

```
Data Source=.\\MYINSTANCE;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=true
```

The Grant syntax I am trying alter is:

```
sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(
    @"GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON tblUnits TO [INET_ACCOUNT]", sqlConnection);
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now my database owner is : Andy-PC\Andy I am wondering what to replace the TO [INET_ACCOUNT] for with my current setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know its [INET_ACCOUNT] refers to the principal to which the permission is being granted. So you would be updating that with the user requiring the Select access for that table. Following is the syntax for GRANT from MSDN:  
    `GRANT <permission> [ ,...n ] ON 
    [ OBJECT :: ][ schema_name ]. object_name [ ( column [ ,...n ] ) ]
    TO <database_principal> [ ,...n ] 
    [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
    [ AS <database_principal> ]
    <permission> ::=
    ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] | permission [ ( column [ ,...n ] ) ]
    <database_principal> ::= 
        Database_user 
    | Database_role 
    | Application_role 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_Windows_User 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_Windows_Group 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_certificate 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_asymmetric_key 
    | Database_user_with_no_login` .

Comment: SO - if  I am using integrated security, and my user is Andy-PC\Andy I replace it with TO [ANDY-PC\\Andy]?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was yes TO[Andy-PC\Andy] fixed the problem!